# How to replace these smileys using javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I am not able to replace these smileys with javascript

> : , >:O ,  >:(

I have used str replace function but it's not working..I wanted to replace it with another string..Whether ti's possible?

Code:

```
     var a =str.replace(">:(","");
```

And stop commenting that you need code..I have already said that I am using str replace !

Comment: Please actually show your existing code and describe what isn't working and what results you're currently getting.

Comment: Paste you code, we will take a look.

Comment: You have to escape the special characters.  I find this regex cheat sheet extremely handy: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/

Comment: @Shan Just like PriorityMark says. And don't forget to double escapes, if you use a string to create a pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One trick to replace all occurrences of a substring without regex is to use `split` and `join`:

```
str = str.split ('>:(').join ('some html');
```

Comment: This is awesome! Initially did not understand :) You saved my day.